# asp.net update panel label text change

Tags: asp.net

i have a code ,where i want to change the lable text and visible mode in code behind file.my page is .ascx page

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlTrvLogin" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
  <div id="divErrMsg" runat="server" style="padding-left: 11px;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblErrMsg" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="False" 
     CssClass="errorIcon" meta:resourcekey="lblErrMsgResource2"></asp:Label>
   <br />
  </div>
<div style="display: inline; float: right; text-align: right; margin-top:   10px; margin-right: 13px;">
   <asp:Button ID="lnkSubmit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                                                  CssClass="font1_2em bolder inButton showHand" OnClick="lnkSubmit_Click" 
    Text="Sign In" UseSubmitBehavior="False"        meta:resourceKey="lnkSubmitResource2"  />
</div>

 </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

code behind file

```
protected void lnkSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
string User = GetUserDetail(txtUsername.Text.Trim(), txtPass.Text.Trim(),out personGuid, false);
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmptyUser (User )
                        {
                            lblErrMsg.Text = "Invalid email / password";
                            lblErrMsg.Visible = true;
                            return;
                        }
}
```

but in the button click event when i an try to change the Label  text but is not changing . please tell why text of label is not changing.

Comment: You'll need to give either the js file, or the .cs button handler (whichever you are trying to use). Can't tell much from the aspx code alone.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you code, seems it is incorrect.
string.IsNullOrEmpty(User) was the correct statement, but you are using string.IsNullOrEmptyUser (User ).

Another tip, don't use variables with first letter on upper case, let it only for class.